# How to display different information for each user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to Rails and I just finished [this](http://andreapavoni.com/blog/2013/8/a-rails-4-tutorial-application-for-beginners) tutorial. It shows you how to build an aplication where you have users that can create notes but the problem is that everyone can see the notes created by all the users. I want each user to have their own notes that only them can see.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information, if you want some help. What does your view and controller look like?

Comment: Links can be useful as supplemental information, but nobody is going to read through the tutorial to figure what you're referring to. You need to provide the [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide specific explanation. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to read the linked blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each user to see only his post, it means that you need some kind of basic authentication. It will allow you to determine which posts a user can see when he logs in.

1. There are some gems that allow to implement this feature, on of them is [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
   When you install devise you will be get a method: current_user in your controllers.
   So with that method you can easily refer to user notes. Of course you will need to create association between user and notes model first.
2. Or you can generate a unique id for each user, and store it in cookies. Each time request comes you check if there is a unique id in the cookie. Each time user create a note you store this user_id in the notes table. After that you can retrieve all notes for specific user:

   @notes = Note.where(user_id: user_id)

Hope this helps, good luck

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you need to replace directs call to your Note model and instead use the relationship it. e.g.:

```
def index
    # retrieve all users Note ordered by descending creation timestamp
    @notes = current_user.notes.order('created_at desc')
end
```